# Do I need to give biometrics for the visa application to continue?

Tags: visas, canada

I applied for a Canadian visa and now the status messages say "We will send you a message when we start reviewing your eligibility... We are processing your background check... We need your fingerprints to process your application."
Does this mean that I need to finish the biometrics part before my visa application can continue, or these parts are independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We need your fingerprints to process your application

If they say you need to submit them for them to be able to process, then you need to submit them, how to do so should be explained.

They are doing a background check (checking with police, immigration...) and they check your fingerprints across the relevant databases